# Redirect From one page to another page using htaccess

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess

I have a website with images in different categories. I used to create webpages manually until i cam to know about dynamical webpages (using mysql and php) .

My current URL is similar to below URL.

```
http://www.example.com/category/alone/1.php
```

What i needed is to redirect all the files which i manually created to corresponding dynamic created pages. My Dynamic page corresponding to above URL is given below.

```
http://www.example.com/category/alone/1/
```

Now i am using 301 redirection on each page to new corresponding  page. And  it takes large  time to do.  Can we do this using .htaccess ?

Comment: You should lookup an example, try it, and ask when you get stuck, posting what you tried.

Comment: Have you considered just turning on `MultViews-Option` to make the `.php` suffix optional?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/.]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2/%3/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*?)/?$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```